# How to calculate the average of values in Col. B, if Col. A contains a unique timevalue of Col. C?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

This is how my table looks:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 08:00:00 | 80 | 08:00:00 | 240 |
| 2016-01-01 08:10:00 | 820 | 08:10:00 | 611.15 |
| 2016-01-01 08:20:00 | 85 | 08:20:00 | 314.15 |
| 2016-01-01 08:30:00 | 500 | 08:30:00 | 533 |
| 2016-01-02 08:00:00 | 400 |  |  |
| 2016-01-02 08:10:00 | 403 |  |  |
| 2016-01-02 08:20:00 | 544 |  |  |
| 2016-01-02 08:30:00 | 606 |  |  |

- I want to display in Column C the **unique** time values of Column A. This would mean: `08:00:00`, `08:10:00`, `08:20:00` and `08:30:00`.
- and in Column D the **average value** of Column B if Column A contains the unique value of Column C.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the `TIMEVALUE` of  first column, You can use `QUERY` to group the data and find averages:

```
=QUERY(
  {ARRAYFORMULA(TIMEVALUE(A1:A8)),B1:B8}, 
  "Select 
    Col1,avg(Col2) 
    group by Col1 
    format Col1 'hh:mm:ss' ",
  0
)
```

Comment: I like this approach

Answer (score 0):

Populating column C with the unique values in column A is easy.

in cell C1 put the formula

```
=unique(A:A)
```

it will be treated as an array formula and populate the column.

The formula for the average is more complex, and has a manual portion.

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,C:C,B:B)
```

The manual portion is that it has to be copied to each cell in column D that has a value in Column C.

Answer (score 0):

**C1:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A8);RIGHT(A1:A8;8)))`**

**D1:** **`=UNIQUE(C1:C8)`**

**E1:** **`=IFS( D1 = ""; ""; D1 <> ""; AVERAGEIF($C$1:$C$8;$D$1:$D$8;$B$1:$B$8))`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Single Formula in `C1`

```
=LET(
   times,ARRAYFORMULA(MOD(1/(1/A:A),1)),
   BYROW(UNIQUE(times), LAMBDA(row,
     IFERROR({row, AVERAGEIF(
       times, row, B:B)}))))
```

## Explanation

#### date_time vs. time

Dates, times, and date_time are all stored as numbers where 1 is equivalent to a day (24 hours). Any portion of a day (time) will necessarily be less than 1.  So returning the time portion is as simple as either of:

1. Subtracting the Integer portion 
   `date_time-INT(date_time)=time`
2. Using the MOD function 
   `MOD(date_time, 1)=time`

#### Date_Times Range to Times

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MOD(1/(1/A:A),1))
```

#### Unique Times

```
=UNIQUE(times)
```

#### Combined Formula

```
=LET(
   times,ARRAYFORMULA(MOD(1/(1/A:A),1)),
   BYROW(UNIQUE(times), LAMBDA(row,
     IFERROR({row, AVERAGEIF(
       times, row, B:B)}))))
```

-BYROW passes each unique time row-by-row into a LAMBDA function stored as `row`

- LAMBDA's formula returns a two-column array for each `row` passed in:

  - value of `row` in column 1
  - Value of AVERAGEIF function in Column 2
  - IFERROR returns nothing instead of errors